# How do I add a README.md file into the root directory of the generated blog by HEXO?

Tags: github-pages, hexo

My blog is based on `Github Pages` and the program I'm using is `HEXO`

the files that are generated by `HEXO` don't contain a README.md file so I can't make a declaration of my blog on Github repo page.So I want to add a README.md file to the folder that `HEXO` generates.I've tried that add it manually to the folder after using `$ HEXO g` and it is added to successfully.But the problem is that every time I use `$ HEXO g`,the file I added will be deleted by the program.
So I want to that is there any method that make the `HEXO` program generate a README.md file to the blog's root directory automatically everytime I run `$ HEXO g`?
thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have write a [blog](http://baurine.github.io/2015/05/10/hexo_git/) to show how to add README.md to hexo and how to keep all .md files in hexo (for version control), but it's in chinese. :)

At first, you need put README.md under **source** folder, **but it's not enough**.

In **_config.yml**, there is a field called `skip_render` (if it's not exist, create it), you must declare README.md or any other files that need to keep its original format under source folder after this filed, like this:

```
skip_render: README.md
```

if you want to keep more than one file, do like this:

```
skip_render: [README.md, ori_data/*, ori_data/posts/*, ori_data/tags/*, ori_data/categories/*, ori_data/themes/next/*]
```

my folder tree is like this:

```
D:\hexo_blog>tree source /F
D:\HEXO_BLOG\SOURCE
│  README.md
│
├─categories
│      index.md
│
├─ori_data
│  │  config.yml
│  │
│  ├─categories
│  │      index.md
│  │
│  ├─posts
│  │      2013-02-05-my-blog-in-github.md
│  │      2013-02-06-resolve-goagent-cp65001.m
│  │      2013-03-11-c_stack.md
│  │      2015-05-03-hello-hexo.md
│  │
│  ├─tags
│  │      index.md
│  │
│  └─themes
│      └─next
│              config.yml
│
├─tags
│      index.md
│
└─_posts
        2013-02-05-my-blog-in-github.md
        2013-02-06-resolve-goagent-cp65001.md
        2013-03-11-c_stack.md
        2013-03-18-understand_typdef_funp.md
        2013-03-24-understand_container_of.md
        2015-05-03-hello-hexo.md
```

some notices: the file that want to keep origin format must not start with '_', else it will be ignored when 'hexo generate'.

BTW: I used hexo 3.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to create your file in **sources** folder ? [See EXO doc](http://hexo.io/docs/setup.html#source)

Edit: you can also try [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/)

Comment: NO,i want a README.md file generated in the `/public` directory I've tried add a README.md file to the `/source` directory but after i run `$HEXO g` it become README.html.So your solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `README.mdown` file in your `source` directory :)

Answer (score 0):

Hexo has its own repositories in you github page.

You don't have to add `readme.md` by using hexo command.

Just go to that repositories page, and you'll a hint said "Help people interested in this repository understand your project by adding a README!".

There's a button next to it. Click and begin to Write