# Adding README.md to Hexo on GitHub Pages

Tags: github, github-pages, hexo

I built a Hexo blog and hosted it on GitHub Pages. Since Hexo has no default README.md file, I'd like to add one myself.

I manually added the README.md through the console as 'hexo deploy'. The README file disappeared.

Then I copied the README file into a non-specific local folder and redeployed the website. Hexo parsed the README.md file into README.md.html, which I'm not interested in.

Adding README.md into the public or .deploy folders and running 'hexo g' also results in deleting the file.

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you in the right branch '`gh-pages`' for GitHub pages? (https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/, https://gist.github.com/chrisjacob/833223)

Comment: Also https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/857 can help troubleshoot the hexo setup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer first. Actually, my blog can run well without README.md file. but I still want to know how to add it.

Answer (score 3):

I have answer a same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258660/how-do-i-add-a-readme-md-file-into-the-root-directory-of-the-generated-blog-by-h/31051913#31051913).

you must do as follow two steps:

1. put `README.md` under `source` folder.
2. declare `REAMDE.md` after `skip_render` field in `_config.yml`.

this method is suit for hexo 3.0.1, and I have successed.

Comment: This solution works well for the CNAME name file as well, although you don't need to skip_render that file.